# Alternating Console Background Color - C#

Tags: c#, .net, colors, console, console-application

I am currently trying to create a program that will output certain sets of data. The Data looks like so:

```
 Offer 1:          Economy        $203.20         Jetblue Airways
    Option 1
    Departure: 2017-12-25 - 20:29:00.000             From: JFK               Arrival: 2017-12-25 - 23:06:00.000              At: JAX
    Departure: 2017-12-26 - 07:00:00.000             From: JAX               Arrival: 2017-12-26 - 08:16:00.000              At: FLL
    Departure: 2017-12-26 - 09:14:00.000             From: FLL               Arrival: 2017-12-26 - 11:14:00.000              At: PAP
    Total projected travel time: 14 Hours, 45 Minutes

    Option 2
    Departure: 2017-12-25 - 16:41:00.000             From: JFK               Arrival: 2017-12-25 - 19:14:00.000              At: JAX
    Departure: 2017-12-26 - 07:00:00.000             From: JAX               Arrival: 2017-12-26 - 08:16:00.000              At: FLL
    Departure: 2017-12-26 - 09:14:00.000             From: FLL               Arrival: 2017-12-26 - 11:14:00.000              At: PAP
    Total projected travel time: 18 Hours, 33 Minutes

    Offer 2:          Economy        $216.60         Jetblue Airways
    Option 1
    Departure: 2017-12-25 - 05:45:00.000             From: EWR               Arrival: 2017-12-25 - 08:28:00.000              At: MCO
    Departure: 2017-12-25 - 09:55:00.000             From: MCO               Arrival: 2017-12-25 - 12:07:00.000              At: PAP
    Total projected travel time: 6 Hours, 22 Minutes

    Option 2
    Departure: 2017-12-25 - 20:30:00.000             From: EWR               Arrival: 2017-12-25 - 23:13:00.000              At: MCO
    Departure: 2017-12-26 - 09:55:00.000             From: MCO               Arrival: 2017-12-26 - 12:07:00.000              At: PAP
    Total projected travel time: 15 Hours, 37 Minutes

    Offer 3:          Economy        $218.60         Jetblue Airways
    Option 1
    Departure: 2017-12-25 - 06:00:00.000             From: JFK               Arrival: 2017-12-25 - 08:48:00.000              At: MCO
    Departure: 2017-12-25 - 09:55:00.000             From: MCO               Arrival: 2017-12-25 - 12:07:00.000              At: PAP
    Total projected travel time: 6 Hours, 7 Minutes

    Option 2
    Departure: 2017-12-25 - 21:45:00.000             From: JFK               Arrival: 2017-12-26 - 00:34:00.000              At: MCO
    Departure: 2017-12-26 - 09:55:00.000             From: MCO               Arrival: 2017-12-26 - 12:07:00.000              At: PAP
    Total projected travel time: 14 Hours, 22 Minutes
```

There can be as many as 50 Offers, so as you can imagine the output can get rather long. I was wondering if there was any possible way to programmatically format the background color in a way that each option would alternate back and fourth between two color blocks. For example, if Option 1 has a gray background, Option 2 will have a black one, Option 3 gray, Option 4 black, etc... I don't care what color the Offer text is surrounded by, as long as it is the opposite of what the previous color block was. I tried just setting the background color with Console.BackgroundColor, but it only highlighted the text, leaving the console to be whatever the original color was. I found that you can set the whole console to one color by using Console.BackgroundColor(), then Console.Clear, but this would delete the data in my case. I guess all I'm asking is if it's possible to get a striped background in the console.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you print this? You probably need to space-fill wherever there aren't any characters to apply the background color, but that's just a guess.

Comment: It's just basic Console.WriteLine() output. I don't want to have to guess at the number of tabs needed to fill everything up. But if that's my only option, I may go for it.

Comment: I mean please create a [mcve] and include a screenshot of what you see, and edit one to show what you want to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background color is only applied to columns where you actually print a value. You can print to every column by space-filling the entire row:

```
var width = Console.WindowWidth;
Console.BackgroundColor = System.ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
Console.WriteLine("{0, -" + width + "}", "TestRed");
```

This will print the entire row with a dark red background color.

Comment: YES! Thank you. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Console.BackgroundColor` and set it to any value in enum `System.ConsoleColor`.  You will have to change it on every line for what you're trying to do.  Don't use `.Clear`, just change it as you need for your different blocks.

Read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.backgroundcolor(v=vs.110).aspx).

EDIT:

Here's a code sample.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<ConsoleColor> colors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor)).Cast<ConsoleColor>().ToList();
            foreach (var back in colors)
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = back;
                foreach (var fore in colors)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = fore;
                    Console.Write("Test      ");
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But this just leaves me with the same problem I had. It just highlights the text without changing the background color. Could you give an example of what you mean? Perhaps I'm confused.

Comment: I've added a code sample.  If you can't do something with this... :(

Comment: Once again. It doesn't fix my problem. But thanks a lot for giving it a shot!